# Multi-module Vaadin project generates files into the parent module

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, vaadin

When creating a multi-module Vaadin project and running it from an IDE, sometimes `node_modules` and other generated files and directories are created in the parent module.

This leads to errors when running the project, such as the one below:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-lumo-styles" has already been used with this registry
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/version.js?babel-target=es6:10:16)
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

This happens when your IDE uses the wrong working directory.

You can configure it in IntelliJ or Eclipse by editing your run configuration, and setting the `Working directory` to the directory of the module that you are running.

If you accidentally run the project using the wrong working directory, remember to delete all the artifacts downloaded or generated by Vaadin, or otherwise you might face further weirdness, such as WebPack errors.